# What is the maximums base damage a weapon can start with?

Tags: hyrule-warriors-age-of-calamity

I would like to know if a weapon can reach the highest possible damage before I start adding seals to it that will take a long time to re-farm.

So I would like to know what is the highest possible damage a weapon can have at level 1 when it drops or de-rust/octo-polish?

Answer (score 0):

The Wiki has [a list](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Weapon#Hyrule_Warriors:_Age_of_Calamity) of weapons sortable by attack range limits, with some being ??, presumably meaning unknown.

I'm going to list Link's weapons because he has the most variety. Everyone else, you can just grab their sparse selection and compare in-game, or use the table.

The highest known Min(imum). Base Attack is the "Royal Guard Spear" seems to be the best known, at 42 damage every hit, at Lv 1.

The highest known Max(imum). Base Attack is the "Royal Broadsword" at 55 damage maximum at Lv 1, but with a minimum of 35.